# POO - Try/except - problema con "missing arguments"

Tags: python, poo

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de POO, y lo que estoy necesitando (y no estoy pudiendo hacer) es que si, al instanciar mi objeto, no incorporo los parámetros que pasan a ser los atributos de la clase, el programa pueda devolverme un mensaje. Probé con try/except pero me sigue diciendo que me faltan dos valores. Muestro el código...

```
    class Punto:
        def __init__(self,X,Y):
            try:
                self.x = X
                self.y = Y
                print(str(self.x)+","+str(self.y))
            
            except:
                print("(0,0)")

    punto = Punto()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejercicio en si es simple, el asunto es que necesito que me imprima (0,0) cuando no ingrese nada, y coloque como coloque el try/except me sigue tirando ese error jajaja, por ahí se puede hacer sin un try/except no se... Esa es una de las tantas formas en que lo intenté. De antemano muchas gracias!!

Comment: Necesitas agregar un [mcve], además el código va como texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atrapar errores necesitas encerrar las instrucciones problemáticas con un `try/except`:

```
class Punto:
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.x = X
        self.y = Y

try:
    punto = Punto()
except TypeError as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
```

El error que se produce en este caso es del tipo `TypeError`, que es el único que vamos a atrapar.

El código produce:

```
Error:  __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'Y'
```

pero lo hace desde el `except`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de producir una excepción cuando no pasas argumentos, y tener que manejar después la excepción, lo que puedes hacer es asignar valores por defecto a los parámetros de `__init__()`. De esa forma, cuando omitas esos parámetros, ya no se producirá excepción alguna sino que el objeto quedará inicializado con esos valores por defecto. Me ha parecido entender que eso era lo que buscabas.

Por otro lado, en lugar de imprimir cosas desde `__init__()`, que se considera mala práctica, he implementado el método `__str__()` en el objet. Este método es invocado automáticamente por Python cuando intentes convertir ese objeto a cadena, o imprimirlo. De ese modo se puede hacer `print(punto)` para obtener una representación útil en vez del típico `<Punto object at 0x7fdd32ef8490>`.

```
class Punto:
    def __init__(self, X=0, Y=0):
      self.x = X
      self.y = Y
    
    def __str__(self): # Retornar representación como cadena
      return "({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

punto = Punto()
print(punto)
```

Produciría la salida `(0, 0)`

Comment: Buenisimo!!... Muchisimas gracias!!!